# How to modify json column value in select statement to retrieve result with updated json(without update value in table)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two SQL Server tables `FormSchema` and `AppRoles`.

For the table detail, input details please see the [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0bd3037aa18cd28467219b6ecfb1a715)

I am trying to restructure (create or update/append in existing json value) `AppSchema` column value in select statement based on `SchemaId` column in both tables. And query return updated result without updating in table.

Query:

```
select 
    fs.SchemaId, fs.SchemaName,
    JSON_MODIFY(fs.AppSchema, '$.roles[1]', '{"role":"Test","permissions":{"create":true,"read":true,"update":false,"delete":true}}') as AppSchema
from 
    FormSchema fs
inner join   
    AppRoles ar on fs.SchemaId = ar.SchemaId
```

Where appending json will be create dynamically from `AppRoles` table based on `SchemaId`.

Expected result:

| SchemaId | SchemaName | AppSchema |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | {"roles":[{"role":"Support","permissions":{"create":false,"read":true,"update":false,"delete":false}},{"role":"Test","permissions":{"create":true,"read":true,"update":false,"delete":true}}]} |
| 2 | Jeep | {"roles":[{"role":"CreateRead","permissions":{"create":true,"read":true,"update":false,"delete":false}}]} |

How to get above result through a SQL query with on time modify json in select statement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use an `APPLY` subquery with `FOR JSON` to get the constructed Json output.**

Then you can use `JSON_MODIFY` with `append` to add to the array. You also need to use `JSON_QUERY` to prevent Json escaping:

```sql
SELECT
    fs.SchemaId,
    fs.SchemaName,
    JSON_MODIFY(fs.AppSchema, 'append $.roles', JSON_QUERY(ar.newJson)) AS AppSchema
FROM FormSchema fs
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT (
    SELECT Role AS [role],
        [create] AS [permissions.create],
        [read] AS [permissions.read],
        [update] AS [permissions.update],
        [delete] AS [permissions.delete]
    FROM AppRoles ar
    WHERE fs.SchemaId = ar.SchemaId
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
  ) AS newJson
) ar;
```

If you want to change the existing values in the actual table, you can transform the above into an `UPDATE`

```sql
UPDATE fs
SET AppSchema =
    JSON_MODIFY(fs.AppSchema, 'append $.roles', JSON_QUERY(ar.newJson))
FROM FormSchema fs
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT (
    SELECT Role AS [role],
        [create] AS [permissions.create],
        [read] AS [permissions.read],
        [update] AS [permissions.update],
        [delete] AS [permissions.delete]
    FROM AppRoles ar
    WHERE fs.SchemaId = ar.SchemaId
    FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER
  ) AS newJson
) ar;
```

Comment: This is a possible solution, but if the OP is _...trying to restructure (create or update/append in existing json value_, the `append $.roles` will only solve the `create` part of the problem.

Comment: True, but it's pretty easy to transform to an `UPDATE`, which I've done now

Comment: I'm not sure @Charlieface. The `append` modifier will only add an item in the existing JSON array (with or without an `UPDATE` statement).

Comment: @Zhorov No `append` will also create the Json path if it does not exist, although if it is null then it will remain null https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91533262839dfa114ed9c1b1e8c08d6f

Comment: @Charlieface, you are right, but I'm wondering if a row with values `('1','Support','true','true','true','true'),` in the `AppRoles` table is a possible scenario. In this case the `fs.AppSchema` column will have two items with the same `Role`.

Comment: @Zhorov That is a matter for database design, unique keys etc

Comment: This seems to be the case, @Charlieface and the answer is an appropriate solution. +1 from my side.